# Simplest QT TCP Server

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp, network-programming

What would I need to receive data from a client?

```
QTcpServer Server;
if(!Server.listen("127.0.0.1", 9000)) {
   return;
}   

connect(Server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(ReceiveData()));
```

Is this correct so far? What do I need in ReceiveData? Do I really need another function to receive the data? I would like to save it in a QByteArray

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As this hasn't been answered, here's a really basic example.

In your ReceiveData slot, you would need to accept the connection from the server.

In Qt's QTcpServer this is done by calling nextPendingConnection().

So the QTcpServer's newConnection slot will call your ReceiveData slot.

In your receivedata slot, you can do something like:

```
void ReceiveData()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

    if (!socket)
        return;

    qDebug("Client connected");

    socket->waitForReadyRead(5000);
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();

    qDebug(data.constData());

    socket->close();
}
```

Note: This is a blocking example, the waitForReadyRead will hang the thread for up to 5000 milliseconds.

To do a non blocking example, you need to connect another slot to the new socket's readyread signal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-server-cpp.html

PS:
Yes, you need at least one callback function to:

1) accept new connections

2) Receive and Send data on the connect(s)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the examples but these are way too complicated for something simple I would like to do

Comment: @JohnSmith What you want is oversimplified and can't be done without blocking. Qt is designed with nonblocking sockets and will require a separate accept and receive callback.